# Where to put monger connection in Compojure app for Heroku?

Tags: heroku, clojure, compojure, monger

I created a compojure app using `lein new compojure mongotest` with lein 2.0, and a Procfile `web: lein ring server-headless $PORT`.  This worked fine, but now when I add

```
(def mongolab-url (System/getenv "MONGOLAB_URI"))
(println "mongolab-url")
(println mongolab-url)
(mg/connect-via-uri! mongolab-url)
```

when I try `git push heroku master` Heroku eventually gives me

```
   Compiling mongotest.handler
   mongolab-url
   nil
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException, compiling:(handler.clj:13:1)
    ... 25 more
   Compilation failed: Subprocess failed
   Error encountered performing task 'compile' with profile(s): 'production'
   Suppressed exit
!  Failed to build.
!  Push rejected, failed to compile Clojure (Leiningen 2) app
```

I added these lines at the top level of `handler.clj`.  Some of the older documentation I see the connection is created in `main`, but that must have been for older versions of compojure, as there's no `main` anymore (that I've found) in the generated app.  Where should the connection get established in the current version?  (Or is my Procfile not right?)

(Yes, `MONGOLAB_URI` is defined in `heroku config`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer that worked for me and seems most idiomatic is to put the above connection into a function `init` in that same file (`myproject/handler.clj`)

```
(defn init[] (mg/connect-via-uri! (System/getenv "MONGOLAB_URI")))
```

and update the `project.clj` file  ring descriptor line from

```
:ring {:handler myproject.handler/app}
```

to

```
:ring {:handler myproject.handler/app :init myproject.handler/init}
```

Comment: Seems like a very neat solution. OTOH I don't see where the connection is available to the rest of your program. Do you store the connection from Monger as an atom globally?

Comment: @MondRaymond This was an older version of monger, which stored the connection internally.  The newer API requires you to keep track of the connection explicitly, so it'd be `(def db (atom nil))` `(defn init[] (reset! db (:db (mg/connect-via-uri ...))))`

Answer (score 0):

You don't want side-effects (such as opening a database connection) to happen at namespace load time, which is effectively compile time. Often you can get away with such things, when you are compiling your code when clojure starts up, but in this case heroku is pre-compiling your app into a jar so that it can serve it up more quickly. Now, at compile time, you try to read the `PORT` environment variable; but it is not set until heroku tries to actually run your app.

The solution is to create it only at runtime, eg by doing so in `-main`, or in some other function, or by defining it as a `delay` which you only `force` at runtime.

Comment: But there is no `-main` in the generated compojure app.  Is there an idiomatic place to put this stuff in a compojure app?  Or is it better to open a connection for each db call?